# free-jqgrid autoResizable: false doesn't work

Tags: free-jqgrid

I am migrating from *jqgrid 4.6.0* to *free-jqgrid 4.14.1*, with the intention of maintaining visual look and feel as similar as possible.
I do not want to make columns auto resizable. 
I supposed that *autoResizable* option was false by default, but columns resize as well.
I set grid property *cmTemplate: {autoResizable: false}*, but columns keep on resizing.
Is there a way to let columns keep the width that was defined for each one of them in the colModel property ?

Comment: Please provide **the demo**, which reproduces the problem. At least you should provide JavaScript code, which you use to create jqGrid. You can get some jsfiddle example from [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and modify it so, that one can see the problem. Moreover you use two thing: auto-resizing and resizing (see "but columns resize as well"). Auto-resizing (on load or on double click on between column headers) and resizing (by user) are two different things. What you really want to implement or protect by which actions of the user?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll clean my code and provide a demo. I'm speaking only about auto resizing, the new feature you introduced in free-jgqrit ( not about resizing ). I want to prevent on load auto resizing, so that columns get loaded with the width they were defined in the column model.

Comment: On load auto resizing will be done only you explicitly include the option `autoresizeOnLoad: true` (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column), where I described the feature). No other resizing on load exist. On the other size you could use `autowidth: true` option, which changes the width of columns too. By the way, you can look at [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/316) with the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/01th999n/5/, which shows one scenario of using `autoresizeOnLoad: true` only on the first page.

Comment: I fiddled around a bit with your demo and verified that the propierties autoResizable, autoresizeOnLoad and autowidth work exactly as you described ( I have tested true, false and default values for each of these properties ). I have to figure out what is wrong with my code. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: After looking into detail I realized that jqgrid columns visible width are a bit larger than free-jqgrid columns width. This led free-jqgrid total grid width to be smaller than jqgrid size: the more columns you have the bigger the difference between both grids. This led me incorrectly to assume that the difference had to do with the new autoResizable property. So I confirm that although there is a difference in the visible final width of the entire grid, it has nothing to do with auto resizable property.